# Error 404 al refrescar la página en vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aplicación-web, vue-router

Desarrollé un sitio en Vue 3, usé vue-router para el manejo de rutas, en mi localhost funcionaba perfecto, pero cuando lo subí a un servidor de NameCheap con Cpanel que funciona bajo Apache, al actualizar en el navegador la URL (midominio/path) envía un error 404.

Leí un poco la documentación de Vue y por el tipo de mi servidor en el .htaccess hice esto:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Luego leí sobre el modo history y en mi indes.js hice esto:

```
 import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

 const router = createRouter({
   mode: "history",
   history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
   routes,
 });

 export default router;
```

archivo index.html (los href y src probados con: '/', './', '')

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="">

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <title>Solincosta</title>
  <link href="js/about.892a2c7a.js" rel="prefetch">
  <link href="css/app.72a269e5.css" rel="preload" as="style">
  <link href="css/chunk-vendors.26a1c8d2.css" rel="preload" as="style">
  <link href="js/app.d5796cb2.js" rel="preload" as="script">
  <link href="js/chunk-vendors.d75bf26f.js" rel="preload" as="script">
  <link href="css/chunk-vendors.26a1c8d2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/app.72a269e5.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

    <body>
      <noscript><strong>We're sorry but solincosta doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it
        to continue.</strong></noscript>
     <div id="app"></div>
     <script src="js/chunk-vendors.d75bf26f.js"></script>
     <script src="js/app.d5796cb2.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Estructura del proyecto

**css**

- app.72a269e5.css
- chunk-vendors.26a1c8d2.css

**fonts**

**img**

**js**

- about.892a2c7a.js
- about.892a2c7a.js.map
- app.d5796cb2.js
- app.d5796cb2.js.map
- chunk-vendors.d75bf26f.js
- chunk-vendors.d75bf26f.js.map

**favicon.ico**

**index.html**

Pero sigo con el mismo problema, me hace falta algo o estoy haciendo algo mal para poder solucionar el problema?

Comment: A mi me paso, lo que hice fue lo siguiente. En la carpeta dist, donde me dejó todos los minificados, fui a index.html y lo abri con vs code. lo indenté con alt+shift+a (en mac tengo ese comando para ejecutar el formatter) para poder leerlo, y reemplacé todas las rutas. Es decir, apuntaba a los archivos  de la forma ``src="./js/chunk-vendors...``, lo que hice fue eliminar el punto, dejando ``src="/js/chunk-vendors...``. Lo mismo para todos los css, favicon, etc. Directamente aprete ctrl+ f y reemplace ``="./`` por ``="/``

Comment: cuando cargas la página, salta algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: @AgustinG. traté de hacer lo mismo pero ya estaban así ="/ probé todas las opciones, puse el punto ="./ y luego quité todo, pero no se arregló.

Comment: @Alpha Lo único que muestra la consola es: Navigated to https//dominio/path
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for /js/chunk-vendors.d75bf26f.js.map

Comment: deberias mostrar la estructura de tus archivos y carpetas dentro de dist, asi podemos ver qué es lo que hay que acomodar

Comment: @AgustinG. ya lo edité con la estructura

Comment: @DiegoMartinez podrias poner el error que te sale, por ultimo? muchas gracias (si dice solo 404 o está indicando que no encuentra algun archivo. Si probaste todas esas variantes tal vez el problema sea otro)

Comment: No sale mas error, sólo el 404, al parecer es el servidor porque probé en otro servidor y funciona perfecto, pero tengo esa duda, ambos servidores son Cpanel y funcionan con Apache, pero no sé que opción debo pedirle al proveedor de hosting que modifique